# Firebase troubleshooting contact

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

The contact form doesn't work: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

I keep getting an error on sending the message.

The problem is: 
Suddenly a function is killed again and again:
Function killed. Error: memory limit exceeded
There are a lot of promises after each other:
external api, validation, processing, changing a base64 pdf to a file on storage and so on...
But it worked like a charm, until now.
I thought Firebase could scale up...

Regards, Peter

Comment: Hey Peter. Firebaser here. I just quickly created a support case from the form and it worked fine now. Can you try again and, if it still doesn't work, post any errors you have with it in the question?

Comment: Hi Frank, for some reason I still see the error. The response from https://firebase.google.com/support/submit is {"status": "error"}

I restarted browser and mac, still can't send it. Chosen component is functions, urgency is medium, summery and description filled out...

Comment: Hmmm... I used Functions too, since I you were asking about that. Are there any errors on the JavaScript console of your browser? Any chance that you can try with a different browser?

Comment: Need more info to be any help. Sorry. Try in incognito, share the exact and complete errors.

Comment: Tried it from home now, on a macbook, chrome, incognito...
Error message on right-top of the page is in Dutch (my language) 'Fout bij verzenden van verzoek. Probeer het later opnieuw.'
url is: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/?refresh=1
no console errors
network request is a POST to https://firebase.google.com/support/submit
status code is 200
response text is {"status": "error"}